# recursive function lisp return list

Tags: recursion, lisp

I know this is a newbie question I apologize in advance. I'm writing a recursive function which returns the number of 'o in a given list

```
(defun garde-o (liste)
    (cond
        ((not liste) 0) 
        ((equal (car liste) 'o)  (+ 1 (garde-o(cdr liste)))   )
        ((garde-o(cdr liste))  )
    )
)
```

Instead of returning the number of occurence I would like to return the given list with only the 'o.

Like that:

```
(garde-o '(a o x & w o o))
```

should return => `(o o o)`

I don't want to use `pop`,`push`,`set`... just I can't find of to return this.

Comment: That's not python. It's lisp.

Comment: No I wrote too quickly it was lisp of course. Apologize.

Comment: Have you made attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: Use the `cons` Luke. Use not non-functional you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that given the number of occurrences, for example 10, you can simply do

```
(make-list 10 :initial-element 'o)
```

or equivalently

```
(loop repeat 10 collect 'o)
```

To count the 'o in your list, you can do

```
(count 'o '(a b c o p o a z))
```

Thus, a simple solution for your function would be

```
(defun garde-o (a)
    (make-list (count 'o a) :initial-element 'o))
```

---

However, you can do this recursively too

```
(defun garde-o (a)
    (cond ((null a) nil)
          ((eq (car a) 'o) (cons 'o (garde-o (cdr a))))
          (t (garde-o (cdr a)))))
```

and non-recursively

```
(defun garde-o (a)
    (loop for x in a when (eq x 'o) collect x))
```