# Lisp recursive function, return list

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

know this is a newbie question I apologize in advance. I'm writing a recursive function which returns the number of 'o in a given list

```
(defun garde-o (liste)
    (cond
        ((not liste) 0) 
        ((equal (car liste) 'o)  (+ 1 (garde-o(cdr liste)))   )
        ((garde-o(cdr liste))  )
    )
)
```

Instead of returning the number of occurence I would like to return the given list with only the 'o.

Like that:

(garde-o '(a o x & w o o))
should return => (o o o)

I don't want to use pop,push,set... just I can't find of to return this.

Comment: You should avoid re-asking question if down voted earlier. Correct your question and someone will help you. You have already posted :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494515/recursive-function-lisp-return-list

Answer (score 1):

Your current version returns a number which is incremented on each recursion. So your proposed version should work by building a list, extending it on each recursion.

Replace `0` with `‘()`, and `+ 1` with `cons ‘o`.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close,

```
(defun garde-o (liste)
 (cond ((not liste) nil)
  ((equal (car liste) 'o) (cons (car liste) (garde-o (cdr liste))))
  ((garde-o (cdr liste)))))
```

Usage: `(garde-o '(a o x & w o ))` => ( o o )

You just need to pick on your identified car.